# xcode not compiling with empty project

Tags: xcode, macos, caching, project

first of all, i already searched for an answer but with no luck.. i am new in xcode!

i created a project and found out at a later moment that i needed to enable core data, so since i didnt work too much on it i decided to start new. ideleted the project folder and set up a new project with the same name. BUT this project does not run. it hit s a breakpoint and throws error after error. project is empty.. if i make the exact same thing with a project that has another name then it works fine. is there sort of a cache somewhere that is interfering with my project? how can i have my new project with the same name?

thanks

Igor

Comment: Your first project had core data ?

Comment: dont remember.. i had to enable something that i forgot, it might be core data or document based project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create project with same name with having use of core data, then your model for core data should be exactly the same. Otherwise it will not read will get crashed.

Try cleaning the targets by  ⌥⇧⌘K <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.